# How to lock move, rename and delete operation of NSDocument file?

Tags: macos, nsdocument

I am working on Mac OS multi-document application that uses NSDocument. I need lock rename, remove and move file operations when document is opened. How can I do it? I found `lockDocument`method, but it locks file for writing too and it allows rename root folder.